# "Pointer to an object" vs. "pointer to an object type"

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, terminology

While reading the C11 standard I'm confused with the meaning of terms "pointer to an object" and "pointer to an object type" and with the
consistency of using these terms in the standard.

Per my understanding:

- "pointer to an object" is the value of a pointer
- "pointer to an object type" is the pointer itself

Is this understanding correct?

Now consider C11, 6.3.2.3p7 (emphases added):

> A *pointer to an object type* may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
> resulting pointer is not correctly aligned 68) for the referenced type, the behavior is
> undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer. When a *pointer to an object* is converted to a pointer to a character type,
> the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.

Here we see that both terms "pointer to an object type" and "pointer to an object" are used with the same verb "converted". So, what exactly is converted: the value of a pointer or the pointer itself?

Another example: C11, 6.5.6p7 (emphasis added):

> For the purposes of these operators, a *pointer to an object* that is not an element of an
> array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
> type of the object as its element type.

Consider C11, 6.5.6p7 (emphasis added):

```
int* x[1];
```

What exactly the array `x` contains: "pointer to an object" or "pointer to an object type"?

---

UPD. While experimenting with pointer to *not* an object type it was found that ICC and MSVC lack generation of diagnostics for constraint violations: https://godbolt.org/z/77Y5snM4K.

Comment: What is the difference between "the value of a pointer" and "the pointer itself"?

Comment: Because `x[1]` can be expressed as `*x`  `int * x[1]` can be expressed as `int **x`, so it would be a pointer to a pointer.  A pointer points to an object type, so in this case the pointer that points to the pointer of an object type, by extension is also pointing to a type.

Comment: "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type." Read this as: "A pointer *which is* a pointer to an object type", i.e., "A pointer *which points at something with* an object type", i.e., "A pointer *which can point at* an object".

Comment: @ScottHunter For `int y; int* x = &y;` I was thinking that "the pointer itself" is `x` while "the value of a pointer" is the address of `y`. Hence, the difference is the context of the term "pointer": compile time vs. run time. According to the answer by HolyBlackCat: at compile time: `x` is a pointer to the object type `int`, at run time: `x` is a pointer to the object `y`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Pointer to an object type"* speaks about the pointer type, as determined at compile-time. An object type is any type other than a function type (C11 6.2.5 Types /1), so they mean pointers to anything other than functions.

*"Pointer to such-and-such object"* speaks about the runtime value of the pointer (which object it points to). "To an object" implies that the pointer is not dangling.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The quote looks ok to me. The "pointer to object" part at the end only works if the pointer points to a valid object.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting your meaning, and you have a point, but I don't think you've quite captured it.  When the spec says "a pointer to an object", it is indeed speaking about the runtime pointer value, but what it is specifically saying is that the value is one that *actually points to an object*, as opposed to being a null or invalid pointer (or a pointer to a function).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've edited to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: A small off-topic: `void` is an object type is C, but not in C++.

Answer (score 1):

> Per my understanding:
>
> - "pointer to an object" is the value of a pointer
> - "pointer to an object type" is the pointer itself
>
> Is this understanding correct?

No. Both are used to refer to a *value* of pointer type (but not of a pointer-to-function type).  The latter is also sometimes used to refer to a type itself, but that is clear in context.

When you say "the pointer itself", I take you to mean an *object* (that is, a region of storage) whose contents are interpreted as having pointer type.  The language spec is generally pretty explicit when it is talking about objects rather than values stored in them.

The difference between the two terms is that a "pointer to an object" is a "pointer to an object type" that actually points to an object, as opposed to being a null or invalid pointer, or having an indeterminate value.  It follows that one can also consider the characteristics of the particular object to which a pointer to an object points.

With respect to your particular examples:

- All type conversions discussed by the spec are from a *value* of one type to a value of a different type.  There is no other meaningful sense of runtime conversion, because the type attributed to an object (that is, a specific area of storage) does not change during that object's lifetime.<sup>*</sup>

  Thus, when 6.3.2.3p7 says "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type," it is talking about the conversion of a pointer value from one (pointer) type to another.  That particular provision is not limited based on the specific pointer values involved.

  When it later says "When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type," it is describing a specific effect obtained when a *valid* pointer value is converted to, say, type `char *`.  That effect does not make sense if the original pointer is null or invalid, and it does not apply to pointers to functions.
- As for pointers to scalars, the spec use the "pointer to an object" form because it's expressing a rule that applies only to pointers that point to objects with the specific characteristic of not being an array element.  The same does not apply to pointer values of the same type that point to array elements or are null or invalid.  This matters because the context is the spec defining pointer arithmetic in terms of arrays into which the pointers involved point.

> Consider C11, 6.5.6p7 (emphasis added):
>
> ```
> int* x[1];
> ```
>
> What exactly the array x contains: "pointer to an object" or "pointer
> to an object type"?

The single element of array `x` is an object of type "pointer to `int`".  The stored value of that element is therefore interpreted according to that type, as *a* "pointer to `int`".  The value is the kind of thing that the spec means when it says "a pointer to an object type".

Such a stored value value might or might not be a pointer to an object.  Immediately following this ...

```
int y;
x[0] = &y;
```

... that value *is* a pointer to an object.  Immediately following this ...

```
x[0] = NULL;
```

... that value *is not* a pointer to an object.

---

<sup>*</sup>Unless the object has allocated storage duration, in which case a write to it can change its effective type.  But conversions, as the language spec uses the term, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

6.3.2.3/7 is meant to be read as “pointer to *object type*” as opposed to “*pointer to object* type”, as in “*not* pointer to function type.”

Pointers to objects are different from pointers to functions and have different rules of behavior.  A pointer to `char` (`char *`) can be converted to a pointer to `int` (`int *`), although the pointer value may no longer be valid.  A pointer to function returning `char` (`char (*)()`) cannot be converted to a pointer to function returning `int` (`int (*)()`).